# Drupal 7 Multiple Display Types Different Options?

Tags: 7, views

I have one view with two display types (two blocks), for one of them I want to limit it to 1 result, for the other I want it to show all the results.

How can I do this? I can't seem to figure out how to allow one display type to override the other. They keep to copy eachother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module, you can build pages using views blocks.
When you select a block you are looking for to include, you can alter on the fly the paging mecanism.
So for the first one : only 1 row, and for the second one : all rows ...

---

Alternatively setting the paging parameter for a specific block is done into a popin in the Views backoffice. On left top corner of this popin you have a select box which allow you to select "This block (override)". Doing this, will setup different parameters for only this block. All parameters in views can be setup like this : global or override.

Comment: That's not what I want, I want to limit the amount of results for one view display. IE turn on allow override for one view display. I just don't remember how.

Comment: Setting the paging parameter is done into a popin. On left top corner of this popin you have a select box which allow you to select "This block (override)". Doing this, will setup different parameters for only this block. All parameters in views can be setup like this : global or override.

Comment: Can you update your answer with that. I will mark it as correct. And thanks btw!

Answer (score 0):

You can have two blocks of the same view with different output.

On Block one, go to the section where you choose the output.  Make sure you select overide this block/view at the top left corner.  Save your changes.  Do the same thing on your second block.  This was you will leave your Master set up intact, and over ide the individual blocks.  It sounds like you are overwriting the master each time you save.